# UICollectionView - Return UICollectionViewCell in a for loop

Tags: swift, xcode

Lately I had problems dealing with this issue.
I have 2 UICollectionViewCells prepared and an object stored in an array.

Now even though I have return statements, the error message keeps on showing up. I know that in order to fix the issue I have to return a cell no matter what happens. But this is the only code I wrote in my function and I don't know what else to do.

[image: How can I fix the error message?]

Comment: Don't post code as image; copy your code to the question and use code blocks to format it.

Comment: You should not have a loop at all. Get the data based on the `indexPath`.

Comment: I've seen that code before. I still don't understand why do you a for loop there. Because `friendList[0]` should do the same. And then I don't understand why `friendList` an array at all.

Answer (score 1):

friendShipList could have 0 elements, you need to put a return statement outside the loop if you want remove that error. Also, it's a really bad a idea to put a loop there. If you need to access to some element in the array, you can do:

```
let friend = friends[indexPath.row]
```

I'm just assuming you are trying to show a list of friends.

Comment: Okay, I get that. But I also want to go through the object and put all the ones which have a 1 in one custom cell and the ones that have a 2 in the other. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because of the `for` loop, which is unnecessary anyways. You should access the element corresponding to the row of the actual index path.

Remove the `for` loop and append this to the beginning of your function:

```
let friend = friends[indexPath]
```

Comment: Your last line should be based on `indexPath`, not hard coded to `0`.

Comment: You can't use an `IndexPath` instance as an array index.

Comment: Okay, I get that. But I also want to go through the object and put all the ones which have a 1 in one custom cell and the ones that have a 2 in the other. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Answer of Your newly [Question that is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604813/uicollectionview-two-sections-with-different-custom-cells-for-each)

Try this code this will solve your issue.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    friendsList.sort { (first: Friends, second: Friends) -> Bool in
        first.confirmed < second.confirmed
    }

    let friend = friendsList[indexPath.row]
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if friend.confirmed == 1 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "addDiscoverCell", for: indexPath) as! addDiscoverCell
            cell.profileImageView.image = nil
            cell.profileLabel.text = friend.username
            cell.partyLabel.text = ""
            return cell
        }
        else if friend.confirm == 2 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "addDiscoverCell", for: indexPath) as! addDiscoverCell
            cell.profileImageView.image = nil
            cell.profileLabel.text = ""
            cell.partyLabel.text = ""
            return cell
        }
        else
        {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "addDiscoverCell", for: indexPath) as! addDiscoverCell
            cell.profileImageView.image = nil
            cell.profileLabel.text = ""
            cell.partyLabel.text = ""
            return cell
        }
    } else {
        if friend.confirmed == 2 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "discoverCell", for: indexPath) as! discoverCell
            cell.profileImageView.image = nil
            cell.profileLabel.text = friend.username
            cell.partyLabel.text = ""
            return cell
        }
        else if friend.confirm == 1 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "discoverCell", for: indexPath) as! discoverCell
            cell.profileImageView.image = nil
            cell.profileLabel.text = ""
            cell.partyLabel.text = ""
            return cell
        }
        else
        {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "discoverCell", for: indexPath) as! discoverCell
            cell.profileImageView.image = nil
            cell.profileLabel.text = ""
            cell.partyLabel.text = ""
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```